# JSON-RPC estimate gas error

Tags: json-rpc, gas-estimate

I am calling method with params:

```js
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"eth_estimateGas",
  "params": [
    {
      "to": "0x8f0921f30555624143d427b340b1156914882c10",
      "data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000001fb330ab08bdba6e218e55fabc357643cf8252e300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005af3107a4000"
    }
  ],
  "id":1
}
```

But I always get an error:

```js
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "error": {
    "code": -32000,
    "message": "gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction"
  }
}
```

[0x8f0921f30555624143d427b340b1156914882c10](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8f0921f30555624143d427b340b1156914882c10) this is address of some ERC-20 Token. When i put instead this Contract address someone other everything works great. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `eth_estimateGas` JSON-RPC call eventually results in a 'trial execution' of the contract function defined in the `data` field.  For an ERC20 transfer, this function may (typically does) look like this:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
```

Notice that there is a non-local reference to `msg.sender` and a `require()` on the sender's balance.

Try adding a `from` field to your JSON-RPC `params` data; that should provide a value in `msg.sender` and allow the `require()` to succeed, hopefully.

Note: it surely isn't intuitive that estimating gas would demand a balance check.

Comment: Most probably addint `from` parameter to your `eth_estamiteGas` call will solve the problem.